# Remove single elements from a vector

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing

I have a vector M containing single elements and repeats. I want to delete all the single elements. Turning something like `[1 1 2 3 4 5 4 4 5]` to `[1 1 4 5 4 4 5]`.

I thought I'd try to get the count of each element then use the index to delete what I don't need, something like this:

```
uniq = unique(M);
list = [uniq histc(M,uniq)];
```

Though I'm stuck here and not sure how to go forward. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result with the following code:

```
A = [a.', ones(length(a),1)];
[C,~,ic] = unique(A(:,1));
result = [C, accumarray(ic,A(:,2))];
a = A(~ismember(A(:,1),result(result(:,2) == 1))).';
```

The idea is, add ones to the second column of `a'`, then `accumarray` base on the first column (elements of `a`). After that, found the elements in first column which have accum sum in the second column. Therefore, these elements repeated once in `a`. Finally, removing them from the first column of `A`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using [**`unique`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), [**`histcounts`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) and [**`ismember`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
tmp=unique(M) ;            %finding unique elements of M
%Now keeping only those elements in tmp which appear only once in M
tmp = tmp(histcounts(M,[tmp tmp(end)])==1); %Thanks to rahnema for his insight on this 
[~,ind] = ismember(tmp,M); %finding the indexes of these elements in M
M(ind)=[];
```

---

`histcounts` was introduced in R2014b. For earlier versions, [**`hist`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) can be used by replacing that line with this:

```
tmp=tmp(hist(M,tmp)==1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cheaper alternative:

```
[s ii] = sort(a);
x = [false s(2:end)==s(1:end-1)]
y = [x(2:end)|x(1:end-1) x(end)]
z(ii) = y;
result = a(z);
```

Assuming the input is

```
a =

1   1   8   8   3   1   4   5   4   6   4   5
```

we sort the list `s` and get index of the sorted list `ii`

```
s= 

1   1   1   3   4   4   4   5   5   6   8   8
```

we can find index of repeated elements and for it we check if an element is equal to the previous element

x =

```
0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1
```

however in `x` the first elements of each block is omitted to find it we can apply `[or]` between each element with the previous element

```
 y = 

1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1
```

we now have sorted logical index of repeated elements. It should be reordered  to its original order. For it we use index of sorted elements `ii` :

```
z =

1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1
```

finally use z to extract only the repeated elements.

```
result = 

1   1   8   8   1   4   5   4   4   5
```

Here is a result of a test in Octave* for the following input:

```
a = randi([1 100000],1,10000000);

-------HIST--------
Elapsed time is 5.38654 seconds.
----ACCUMARRAY------
Elapsed time is 2.62602 seconds.
-------SORT--------
Elapsed time is 1.83391 seconds.
-------LOOP--------
Doesn't complete in 15  seconds.
```

*Since in Octave `histcounts` hasn't been implemented so instead of `histcounts` I used `hist`.

You can test it [Online](http://rextester.com/LBXW64710)

Answer (score 0):

```
X = [1 1 2 3 4 5 4 4 5];
Y = X;
A = unique(X);
for i = 1:length(A)
    idx = find(X==A(i));
    if length(idx) == 1
        Y(idx) = NaN;
    end
end
Y(isnan(Y)) = [];
```

Then, `Y` would be `[1 1 4 5 4 4 5]`. It detects all single elements, and makes them as `NaN`, and then remove all `NaN` elements from the vector.